# ReportViewer shows blank space

Tags: c#, rdlc

i got problem about ReportViewer.
I have a RDLC that shows report from database, but i shows blank, even the green circle is not there.
I assume my RDLC contain some error, so i create new RDLC that contain only one TextBox with "Yeahh!" text. and it show nothing.

so, there's no error in my RDLC, but in my client code to process it.

this is my code to showing it. please help me and let me know if something's is missing or wrong.

```
Report.aspx

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/CSS/GlobalStyle.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/CSS/UCStyle.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="borderedView">
    <br />
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer3" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Width="100%"
        Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" AsyncRendering="false"
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" CssClass="avoid-clicks">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="56000">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
</div>
```

```
Report.aspx.cs

/*Updated part - Get data*/
dsTemp = _presenter.GetData();

ReportViewer3.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewer3.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report/" + "Hoho" + ".rdlc");
ReportViewer3.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;

ReportViewer3.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dataset1", dsTemp.Tables[0]);
ReportViewer3.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: how do you set the data source of the report ? To me it smells like an empty report.

Comment: it's not empty, only shows textbox with text, because i want to tested it with empty report, to know where part is wrong.

Comment: As I said, show us how you set the data source of the report

Comment: @DimitarTsonev i've add the code how to set the data source. thank you

Comment: And you're sure that the datatable has data? Another thing to try is to turn on all exceptions in Visual studio and run the report.  If there is some exception,  it will be thrown.

Comment: i am very sure. i've debug it step-by-step. the dataset contains the data, i can see it from the visualizer. okay, i'll try to turn on all exceptions. thanks @DimitarTsonev